# access element in nested array PHP - array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need have an array structured like so

```
Array
 (
    [id] => 
    [name] => 
    [description] => 
    [table_id] => 
    [records] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [table_id] => 
                    [created] => 2016-01-15T09:19:36-0700
                    [updated] => 
                    [created_by] => 
                    [updated_by] => 
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [created] => 
                            [Delivery Date] => 
                            [Total Price Including Shipping] =>
                            [Enquiry Status] => 
                            [Equipment Booked 1] =>
                            [Equipment Booked 2] => 
                            [Equipment Booked 3] => 
                            [Equipment Booked 4] => 
                            [Equipment Booked 5] =>
                            [Equipment Booked 6] =>
                            [Surname] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [record_count] => 1
)
```

I need to extract the [created] field from the last element of the nested array in [records]. 
I've tried doing the following

```
$target_elems = $target.['record_count'];
//print_r($target_elems);

//echo $target_elems;
//echo $target.['records'].[$target_elems].['created'];
echo '<pre>'; print_r($target); echo '<pre/>';
```

bur I always get Array to String conversion error (commented lines have been tested obviously).

the only generated output is

```
ArrayArrayArrayArray
```

Comment: using  `foreach` with key value pair, you can loop through the array and can retrieve the required value

Comment: htank you for the quick reply, would you be able to provide a sample code on how to retrieve exactly that element with the foreach function please?

Comment: `echo $target.[5].[0].[0];` the dot is the [string concatenation operator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in php. This line of code therefore tries to concatenate the array $target with the array [5] and the array [0] .... as strings. Same Problem with `$target.['record_count']`

Comment: your item number is "target_elems -1" so you should get it with something like this : obj[records][target_elems-1][created] or so

Comment: it worked perfectly!thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said:- `I need to extract the [created] field from the last element of the nested array in [records].`

first count the number of records in  `records` sub-array and then get the data:-

```
<?php
  $count = count($target['records']); // count number of record in records sub-array
  echo $target['records'][$count-1]['created']; // get last created from records array
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `created` field value of last record by below way.

```
$last_record = end($target['records']); // get the last record of an array
echo $last_record['created']; // print value of array key 'created'
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
function ProcessData($arr){
    foreach($target as $key => $value){
        if( is_array($value) and !empty($value) ){
            ProcessData($value);
        }else{
            if($key == 'created'){
                echo $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low-value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Every answer should be explained.  `!empty()` is an unnecessary function call here -- `$value` would do (truthy check).